# batch file ftp authentication issue

Tags: batch-file, ftp

I'm trying to download some files using a batch file, however after reading the username line an error is thrown 'Invalid command'.

In my batch file I call my ftp file as follows:

```
ftp -n -s:ftp_download.txt
```

my ftp_download.txt looks like this:

```
open myname.com
test@myname.com
test
lcd C:\myDownloads
cd download_files
get MY_NEW_FILES_*.xml
bye
```

However after the `test@myname.com` line an error is thrown 'Invalid command' and thus the script does not connect to my ftp server.

When authenticating as follows:

```
open myname.com
user test@myname.com test
```

I get the 'not connected' error

However using this username (test@myname.com) and password (test) I'm still able to connect using Filezilla .

Am I missing a command somewhere?

Comment: Try ftp'ing manually, perhaps the server doesn't require a login. What happens if you send `user test@myname.com test` instead?

Comment: usernames that I have experience with don't use @domain.  Try logging in interactively with the `FTP myname.com` command and type the username in.  If it is not accepted them try again and use `test` without @myname.com to see if that is accepted.

Comment: anonymous login does not work. and leaving the domain out even fails in FileZilla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To those, like CharlesKSQL, who might stumble upon my question.
Here's how I got it to work (it turned out I had to use sftp for some reason so make sure it's enabled on your server);

The script *(ftp_download.txt)* contains the following:

```
option batch abort
option confirm off
open sftp://<username>:<password>@<host> -hostkey="<fingerprint/key>"
option transfer binary
cd <your folder>
get <some file>
```

If you do not know the fingerprint and/or key; you can find these in FileZilla when connecting trough sftp. They are shown in the popup that show up when you connect to your server for the first time or you could click the little lock-icon in the statusbar on the bottom right when you are connected already.

[image: The Lock-icon in FileZilla]

Now to actually connect you'll need a little bit of software (when using Windows) to create the secure connection. I used WinSCP.
You can download the portable executables [here](http://winscp.net/eng/download.php) and place them (for easy usage) in the same folder as your batch file.
Then you can call the executable in your batch file by adding a parameter:

```
winscp.exe /script=ftp_download.txt
```

which should then execute your download script.

P.S.: it's been a while since I finished this, it's still working as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Your text file should look like this:

```
open myname.com
user
<enter username here> <password here>
lcd C:\myDownloads
cd download_files
get MY_NEW_FILES_*.xml
bye
```

Try that and see if it helps
[image]

Comment: This gives the same error. However when I place the `user`command, username and password on the same line he no longer throws the invalid command error but rather states 'not connected'

Comment: have you tried running the command from DOS and see if it works? See attached screenshot. Its not rocket science